# Want to disable image popup dragging on a page using highslide?

Tags: highslide

I want to off the image dragging all over the page. I just want the image to be zoomed in.how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this to your highslide.config.js file, or put it in script tags in the head of your page (after highslide-full.js has been loaded):

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onDrag = function() {
    return false;
}
```

To get rid of the "move" cursor, delete these from highslide.css:

```
.highslide-move, .highslide-move * {
    cursor: move;
}

.highslide-header .highslide-move a {
    cursor: move;
}
```

If you're using any of the wrapper-class names like .draggable-header or .titlebar, you'll need to make further CSS revisions, eliminating the "cursor: move;" attribute wherever you find it in the CSS file.

You'll probably also want to get rid of the "move" icon in the controlbar, but without being able to see your page, I don't know what kind of controlbar you're using, or if you're using one at all.